# Redirect to a login page when accessing androids tethered hotspot

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I have an android device which i want to use to provide internet to a group of people. I want to leave the wifi open but a user must acquire a username and a password to properly login to our internet.

Once a user is connected to our wifi,i want the user to be redirected to our login page. Is there an android hotspot app that can enable me to redirect a user to a custom page?.

Comment: check [this xda thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-setup-fake-captive-portal-android-t4011689/) by me.fully working, shows "sign into wifi" notification also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called `WIFI Captive Login`. Radius server used it. Do some `R&D` on this and hope you will find some thing helpful.

Comment: Would you suggest an app that provides captive login capabilities on android?.

Comment: I don't think it will be available for non-rooted phones. Since it may require you to run a local server inside mobile itself to handle web pages. Try to find it in Xda developers. I never searched for it. So sorry I can't help you in finding app.